# I need to loop this through and have the program terminate when the string -1 is given

Tags: c++, loops, binary, type-conversion

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
using namespace std;
int main (){
//Written By: Hannah Stang
//Reads a Binary number and converts it to a decimal
long decimal = 0, remainder, number, base = 1;
long bin;
    cout << "Enter a binary number: ";
    cin >> number;
    bin = number;
    while (number > 0)
    {
        remainder = number % 10;
        decimal = decimal + remainder * base;
        base = base * 2;
        number = number / 10;
    }
cout << "Conversion to decimal: " << decimal << endl;
return 0;
}
```

The main problem I am having is trying to get the program to run more than once. I need it to keep repeating until I enter -1 as a value.

Comment: You placed the 'while' wrong and you do not check stream states

Comment: @DieterLücking The 'while' is placed fine -- but another 'while' is needed around everything.

Answer (score 0):

Try moving the while loop and start with `number` initialized to 1:

```
long decimal = 0, remainder, number=1, base = 1;

while (number > 0)
{
    cout << "Enter a binary number: ";
    cin >> number;
    bin = number;
    remainder = number % 10;
    decimal = decimal + remainder * base;
    base = base * 2;
    number = number / 10;
    cout << "Conversion to decimal: " << decimal << endl;
}
```

Or you could do something like this:

```
while (1)
{
    cout << "Enter a binary number: ";
    cin >> number;
    if(number == -1)
    {
        cout<<"Program exiting.";
        break;
    }
    bin = number;
    remainder = number % 10;
    decimal = decimal + remainder * base;
    base = base * 2;
    number = number / 10;
   cout << "Conversion to decimal: " << decimal << endl;
}
```

Comment: No good - Presenting a result even a abort is requested, no checking of the stream state, doing homework.

Comment: @HannahStang You're welcome! If it works correctly, repeatedly then please upvote or accept my answer. I'm not sure what Dieter is talking about, his sentence doesn't make sense to me :P

Answer (score 0):

You can do the following:

```C++
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
using namespace std;
int main (){
//Written By: Hannah Stang
//Reads a Binary number and converts it to a decimal
  long decimal = 0, remainder, number, base = 1;
  long bin;
  cout << "Enter a binary number: ";
  cin >> number;
  while (number != -1)
  {
    bin = number;
    while (number > 0)
    {
        remainder = number % 10;
        decimal = decimal + remainder * base;
        base = base * 2;
        number = number / 10;
    }
    cout << "Conversion to decimal: " << decimal << endl;
    cout<< "Enter a binary number: ";
    cin>> number;
  }
  return 0;
}
```

So in other words, just embed your main code in a loop whose condition is number being unequal to -1

Note that I am reading number in the end of the body of the loop, so that if the user enters -1 he exits immediately.